# Fast way to find the __regular__ part of the Laurent expansion of a function at a pole?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

To evaluate a certain limit, I need to calculate the first term in the **regular** part of the Laurent expansion of the function
$$\frac{\pi}{\sin \frac{\pi(s+1)}{2}}$$
around -1 (should be the same thing as the regular part of $\frac{\pi}{\sin \frac{\pi s}{2}}$ with $s\to (s+1)$ in the argument, I guess). The principal part of the series is obvious. However, the only two ways I know to calculate the regular part is to calculate recursively the multiplicative inverse to the series
$$\frac{1}{\pi} \sin \frac{\pi s}{2}=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k} \left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)^{2k+1}\frac{1}{(2k+1)!}$$
using the fact that
$$\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k} \left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)^{2k+1}\frac{1}{(2k+1)!} \right)\left( \frac{2}{s} + c_{0} + c_{1}s + c_{2} s^2 + \cdots    \right)=\left( \frac{0}{s} + 1 + 0 \cdot s + 0 \cdot s^2 + \cdots \right)$$

or to calculate the $k$-th coefficient by definition, using the contour integral.

I wonder if there is a faster way to calculate the regular part of the Laurent series. People are usually concerned only with calculating the principal part, so I have not found much material on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

By [Mittag-Leffler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem), we have the expansion

\begin{aligned}
{\pi\over\sin(\pi z)}
&=\frac1z+\sum_{n\ge1}(-1)^n\left({1\over z-n}+{1\over z+n}\right) \\
&=\frac1z+\sum_{n\ge1}(-1)^n{2z\over z^2-n^2}.
\end{aligned}

When $|z|<1$, the properties of geometric series indicates that

$$
{1\over z^2-n^2}=-{1\over n^2}\cdot{1\over1-z^2/n^2}=-\sum_{k\ge0}{z^{2k}\over n^{2k+2}}.
$$

Consequently, we have

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n\ge1}(-1)^n{2z\over z^2-n^2}
&=2\sum_{n\ge1}(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{k\ge0}{z^{2k+1}\over n^{2k+2}} \\
&=2\sum_{k\ge0}z^{2k+1}\sum_{n\ge1}{(-1)^{n-1}\over n^{2k+2}}.
\end{aligned}

Using the identity

$$
\sum_{n\ge1}{(-1)^{n-1}\over n^s}=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s),
$$

we conclude that

$$
{\pi\over\sin(\pi z)}=\frac1z+\sum_{k\ge0}(2-2^{-2k})\zeta(2k+2)z^{2k+1}.
$$

Comment: That's a nice solution of this particular problem, but it kinda misses the point. I was asking about general fast methods to find the regular part. Though the Mittag-Leffler series for $\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z}$ is well-known, in general calculating this series is a much more daunting task then solving a recurrence.